# Will uploading our .docx files on scribd and embedding the files on our website affect search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, embed

We have prepared notes for university students which are on .docx format. And we want it to put on our website for viewing.

We tried one option. Uploading the files on scribd and embedding it on our website for viewing on scribd viewer. Will making documents available on srcibd viewer on our website affect search engine rankings ?

Will search engines treat it as duplicate content as those are already uploaded on scribd and we are embedding it on our website ?

On scribd we have set the uploaded documents as 'private' though.

And if it affects, can you suggest any suitable way to make .docx files to be viewed on our website that doesn't affect search engine rankings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may affect in a positive way since you are providing more information about a subject. Of course, my answer takes in consideration that your links to those documents are part of a bigger paragraph or text that describes the document.

If they are just lists of links to documents, the title of the link and the link itself will contribute a bit to rankings due to word density, but not much more.

There should not be any problem about duplicate content, basically because they are private, so the bots can not see them.

If the bots could see the document, they will see that there is a site (yours) pointing to a resource (the document), which is not bad. Considering that scribd only provides the content, but is not an authoring site, it won't be considered as copying yours or you copying them.